# How can I get IIRF Rewrite Filter to run with ColdFusion 9 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, rewrite

I am a programmer trying to move my development environment from Windows Vista to Windows 7. For the most part, it has been much easier than any previous install. But, right at the finish line, I'm hitting a roadblock.

I have installed ColdFusion 9, SQL Server 2011 'Denali', created a new IIS website, and added my IIRF rewrite filter DLL to the IIS site. The ColdFusion pages were being served up without a problem, until I tried to access one that needed a URL Rewrite. So, I searched online and found that I need to update the IIS Application Pool setting Enable 32-bit Applications to "True" in order for the IIRF DLL to work. I did this. Now I am getting HTTP 500.0 errors. I can tell that the IIRF rewrite filter is working, since the correct path to the file is displayed in the error, but I can't serve up ANY ColdFusion files now. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed IIS, ran the ColdFusion WebServer Configuration Tool, removed the IIS Sites from the config, and then added them back as 32-bit applications. All is working fine now.